# Taking potentially multiple user inputs and comparing them to an array to write to an output file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a python code that will read a csv file and then accept user inputs to determine which data from the csv file matches, then write to another csv file.  So far I have been stumped on how to accept multiple user inputs and have created the following code to take them then print the data that matches.

```
with open("Project4Inventory.csv", 'r') as filename:
    contents=filename.readlines()
    
inputFile = input("PRINT INPUT HERE")
inputList = inputFile.split(" ", 3)

    
for contentsArray in range(1, 5):

    if len(inputList) == 1:
        if inputList[0] in contents[contentsArray]:
            print(contents[contentsArray])

    elif len(inputList) == 2:
        if inputList[0] in contents[contentsArray] or inputList[1] in contents[contentsArray]:
            print(contents[contentsArray])

    elif len(inputList) == 3:
        if inputList[0] in contents[contentsArray] or inputList[1] in contents[contentsArray] or inputList[2] in contents[contentsArray]:
            print(contents[contentsArray])
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where is contentsArray declared, what is it? Please edit your question to show that. Also, your question doesn’t really show us what the problem is, so we probably won’t be able to help.